# 401 redirect doesn't work when session expires

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, vb.net, webmethod

Does anyone else have this problem?  The interwebs just give me the phone book on 401s when I google.

I've set my jQuery ajax to redirect back to my login page when a webmethod returns 401.

This works fine if someone isn't logged in and tries, but if the session expires, it doesn't work.  It just sits there.  Does anyone else have this issue?

Thanks in advance!

**Clarity**

It returns 401 if, say, I pull up my browser after booting up, my page is still cached, and I try to ajax a webmethod.  When that happens, my jQuery error handling of the 401 code redirects to the login page like I've told it to.

**However**, if my session expires, it looks like it sends a 401, but the jQuery ajax error handling for the 401 code does not fire.

If this helps, on my older server-side pages, when the session expires and I try to do something, I get the "username and password cannot be null" page which also fails to redirect to the login page as usual.

Is the 401 from a session expiration different than a 401 from simply not even having a session?

Thanks all for your contributions!

Comment: Does the method actually return a `401` if someone is logged in? It may not be and that might be why you aren't properly redirecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answer on "how to search" - the thing you are looking for is "http status code 401" which is "Unauthorized" (RFC2616 i.e. http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

It makes perfect sense for server to return this error when it can't for whatever reason to verify authorization of user. So I don't think anyone have problem with that.